# jQuery Typewatch - alternative or how to create the same functionality?

Tags: jquery, typewatch

I'm using [jQuery Typewatch](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TypeWatch) but it's no longer maintained and I'm having a problem with it.

I'm using it to power an ajax search function. If the user enters a search term, for example "bob", it will perform the ajax callback as expected. However, if the user, or a script, clears the text box containing the search term and then types in "bob" again, it does not trigger the callback to run.

Is there a solution to this problem, or perhaps an alternative plugin to jQuery Typewatch or a way to create the same functionality (run a callback after user has finished typing)?

This is the basic TypeWatch JS. ajaxSearch is a standard jQuery `$.ajax` function.

```
$("#search").typeWatch({
    callback: ajaxSearch,
    wait: 750,
    highlight: false,
    captureLength: 2
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it was self explanatory from the typewatch.js:

```
// Fire if text > options.minTextLength AND text != saved txt OR if override AND text > options.minTextLength
//if ((elTxt.length > options.minTextLength && elTxt.toUpperCase() != timer.text) 
if ((elTxt.length > options.minTextLength)
```

I should've looked there first. But at least it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a fairly simple plugin. I had a quick look at the code and looks simple too.

```
// Fire if text > options.captureLength AND text != saved txt OR if override AND text > options.captureLength
```

This line caught my attention that it is checking the last value before triggering the event. You can also achieve this using simple `change` trigger and some custom logic or you can modify the plugin to suite your needs.