# jQuery: keyup event - ajax return validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'll start with what I'm trying to do.

I've created a "Forgotten Password" system where the user enters their email address and (if correct) they will be sent an email with a reset link.

There is a small section of ajax in the form page which detects if the email entered is in the database. If the email *does* exist in the database the form changes color to green and the submit button is enabled. If the email is not detected the form stays red and the submit button is disabled.

[image]

The issue is that when typing the email address, the keyup event seems to happen when the user has entered one more character than the correct email (basically if *hello@123.com* was in my database, they would have to enter *hello@123.com1* for submit to be enabled)

[Here is my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PzAK/10/) with everything apart from the ajax working.

Here is an example of the ajax file itself:

```
<?php

session_start();

$Email = $_POST['email'];

//Parse ini file containing database information
$databaseInfo = parse_ini_file("optiMizeWebReport.ini", true);

global $con;

//Connect to database
$con = @mysqli_connect($databaseInfo['optiMizeDatabaseConnection']    ['WebServer'],$databaseInfo['optiMizeDatabaseConnection']['Username'],     $databaseInfo['optiMizeDatabaseConnection']['Password'],     $databaseInfo['optiMizeDatabaseConnection']['DBName']);

//Check connection and output error if invalid
if(!$con)
{
    die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Execute query
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE Email='$Email'")
or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

//Initialize
$emailMatch = array();

//Extract
while($emailMatch[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result))


print_r($emailMatch[0][0]);

?>
```

If there is any other information i can give that will help please let me know. Thanks.

## **EDIT:**

*As there still seems to be no quick fix/answer I've made a short video showing exactly what happens. You can see it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-2Gz5b4ek8*

Comment: Use keydown instead of keyup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That didn't work though, I have changed the event to use keyup, keydown and blur but it still isn't instant and still has a sort of delay by one event

Comment: have you tried with `$('#id').on('blur change keyup',function(){})` ?

Comment: Just tried that, and it seems to have the same problems that I've shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-2Gz5b4ek8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax requests are asynchronous! In your case when you check `if(databaseCheck != 1)` the value of `databaseCheck` is previous ajax's response. Thats why you have to type 1 extra character to get last result.

```
$('input').bind("keyup", function() {
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "ForgotPasswordAjax.php",
           data: {email: $('#email').val()},
           success: function(output){
               console.log(output);
               notification(output);
           }
    });
});
function notification(databaseCheck) {
    if (databaseCheck != 1) {
        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }
}
```

on success part call a function like this, it will ensure that these codes will run after ajax success.
It will solve your current issue but you have to prevent simultaneous ajax calls. We have no idea which request return first, if first request response last js will set notification with that response. So you have to add a processing flag to prevent it.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for the insight. It is now working. Could you extend slightly on the processing flag?

Comment: var processing = FALSE, newText = '';
if(!processing){
   _doAjax();
   newText = '';
}else{
   newText = $('#email').val();
}
Move ajax to _doAjax() function.And add this on success part.
if(newText != '')
   _doAjax();

Comment: using type-watch will avoid ajax request for every key-down. Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215152/jquery-typewatch-alternative-or-how-to-create-the-same-functionality

Answer (score 0):

i have updated the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2PzAK/13/).

Here i have included keydown and focus into

```
$('#email').bind("keyup keydown change focus blur", function() {
```

and change below line

```
 $('input').bind("keydown", function() {
```

Comment: Hi no I'm sorry this isnt working, I've made a short video showing exactly what happens though if you need to see its here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-2Gz5b4ek8

Comment: could you pl explain your issue? I am unable to watch video.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has another event called `input`.

```
$('#email').bind("input", function() {
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/2PzAK/15/)