# How to make a real time validation on a form?

Tags: jquery, css, html, validation

I want to make a real time validation for my sign in form. 
My form layout like this

> Username _____________
>
> Password _____________

```
                 Submit
```

When the user type in a valid `username` that match with the `database`, I want to throw in the `green` `check mark` at the end of my form

`OR` red `x mark` vice of versa.

Before the user even hit the `submit`, they kind of know what to expect.

I find that feature is really useful, even big site like Apple use it some part of their site.
So can someone tell me how to make this happen.

HUGE `thanks` to hero of this post !

Comment: You need to make a webservice to check if a username already exists. As the `Username` field loses focus, you will query that service for the user-entered value. That's basically the gist of it.

Comment: You're going to want to look into ajax

Comment: @ZoffDino : Thanks for getting me thinking !! :)

Comment: All you need is `Ajax + jquery event keyup +serverside response`

Comment: @bwegs : Ajax sound `hard` I'm new to the web world. :( ... Is it the only way ?

Comment: Another one with the Ajax, I guess, I should learn it if I want to get this done.

Comment: @iggy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678735/jquery-keyup-event-ajax-return-validation

Comment: Thanks for the link `coolguy`

Answer (score 0):

you want to submit your form (most likely with ajax) on `keyup` which will check your database to see if it exists

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
   //submit your form    
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p6245nbm/)

Comment: so keyup will check my database ?  Your FIDDLE doesn't answer my question :(  Can you be a little more specific please ?

Comment: keyup will trigger a function, inside that function you need to have ajax that will hit your database, check for a match and return the results which you can append to the page. My fiddle is how to set it up, I cant create the ajax association for you since I don't have access to your database

Comment: why would you execute a network request on every key up when you only want to check if the full username is correct, this way you are making an obsolete request for every other character in the username except the last one?

Comment: because a lot of sites that match things in a database on the fly tend to do them on `keyup`...its completely personal preference. Depends on what you're going for. OP might want the user's email to run without them having to `focusout`.

Answer (score 0):

Run your query for the username and password on focusOut event of the respective input field and in the callback of the ajax function add the desired class to the input in question

```
$("#usernameInput").focusout(function(){
   //here goes your query to the database
$.post('functlions.php', { user:$("#username").val()},
    function(data){
        if(data == true){
          $("#username").addClass("check");
        }else if(data == false){
          $("#username").addClass("red");
        }
    }
);

});
```

Comment: What focusout will do ?

Comment: It is going to trigger the query when you click out of the input, just as the examples you mention - for example when you click on the input field for the password the input for the username is going to either show a check mark or the red border